# A questions about affiliate software was inappropriately closed as a duplicate of a question about content management systems

Tags: discussion, specific-question

[This question](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/9882/affiliate-software-to-attract-incoming-customers) asks about affiliate software, but it was closed as a duplicate of [a question that asks about CMS software](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/25745/which-content-management-system-cms-wiki-should-i-use).

Affiliate software is different to CMS software. Please re-open my question.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like that question is over six years old (from 2011), and since it's seeking a recommendation for software, which is considered off-topic for this site, it can't be reopened.

If you check our Help Center's FAQ's on [what topics can I ask about here](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic), you'll see:

> **Recommendations for sites and resources** -- Questions that ask for
>   recommendations of external websites or resources attract lots of self
>   promotion and spam answers. In addition, answers to such questions
>   quickly become out of date. Such questions are closed as off-topic.

Based on the sentence `I'm not sure what CMS or shopping cart software to use yet, but it will need to include an affiliate system to allow advertisers to push customers our way`, it might appear that you were looking for a CMS that *includes an affiliate system*, which is why John likely marked it as a duplicate of our [community wiki](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/edit-community-wiki) that's a catch-all for any questions related to finding a CMS.

You might be able to ask this over at [Software Recommendations](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/), but I'd suggest adding a list of [objective requirements](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) (a minimum set of features) and [a purpose](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) (a task to accomplish) first.

Answer (score 1):

I have unmarked the question as a duplicate and re-closed is with the more appropriate reason:

> Questions asking for **recommended external websites, tools, resources, and software** are off-topic as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Recommendations for software are permitted on [Software Recommendations](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/), but be sure to read their [quality guidelines](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/336) before posting there.